# Compare tree structures in mathematica

Tags: pattern-matching

Since *Mathematica* expression is basically a tree structure, I would like to perform tree structure comparison with certain restrictions, for instance that the identity of nodes on the same level be the same, regardless of order.

For instance, `head1[1, head2[2, 3]]`, should be considered the same as `head1[head2[3,2], 1]`.

Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: Construct a canonical form of the tree by sorting it at each level, then compare as normal with `===`.  Something like `Map[Sort, expr, {0,-2}] === Map[Sort, expr2, {0,-2}]` as a starting point.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure about general way, are you concerned of keeping thing unevaluated for example? Are there any `Locked` heads?

Based on Szabolcs suggestion:

```
test = SameQ @@ (Sort //@ {##})&

test[
  h1[1, h2[3, 2]],
  h1[h2[2, 3], 1]
  ]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Or faster modyfication:

```
ord[h_[x__]] := h @@ Sort[{x}];
ord[x___] := x

SameQ @@ (ord //@ {h1[h2[2, 3], 1], h1[1, h2[3, 2]]})
```

> ```
> True
> ```

---

Another one:

```
Function[expr,
  Block[#,
   SetAttributes[#, Orderless];
   SameQ @@ expr
 ] &@Union[ Flatten[Cases[ #, x_[___] :> x, {0, \[Infinity]}, 
                           Heads -> True] & /@ expr]]
] @ {h1[1, h2[3, 2]], h1[h2[2, 3], 1]}
```

> ```
> True
> ```